# invalid format MST using amazon athena at_timezone function sql/presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

So I have the original where clause like so:

```
 --date_parse(coalesce(nullif(cc.timemodified         , ''),nullif(cc.timecreated         , ''), '2500-01-01 15:01:01    '),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')         >= date_add('hour', -36, date_parse('2022-11-07 14:08:22','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

I want to convert it to be more incremental using the Athena at_timezone function, I have the below so far:

```
at_timezone(parse_datetime(coalesce(nullif(cc.timemodified || 'MST', ''),nullif(cc.timecreated || 'MST', ''), '2022-11-01 22:25:32 MST'),'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'), 'US/Mountain') >= parse_datetime('2022-11-01 22:25:32 EST', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')
              --date_parse(coalesce(nullif(cc.timemodified         , ''),nullif(cc.timecreated         , ''), '2500-01-01 15:01:01    '),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')         >= date_add('hour', -36, date_parse('2022-11-07 14:08:22','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

But this isnt working and producing the error:

```
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "MST"
This query ran against the "some data" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id:
```

where am I messing up?

Comment: What is the point of `nullif(cc.timecreated || 'MST', '')`?

Comment: some columns might be missing data and if it sees that, it grabs the first populated column or if none at all, takes the hard coded date.

Comment: That what coalesce is for. Your `nullif` will not work as expected, case ` nullif('' || 'MST', '')` is unsurprisingly `MST` and not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your format ('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z') works fine for me:

```sql
select parse_datetime('2022-11-01 22:25:32 MST','YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-11-01 22:25:32.000 America/Denver |

It seems that you are missing space in your concat, try adding it - `cc.timemodified || 'MST'` -> `cc.timemodified || ' MST'`

**UPD**

Also you need to fix the `nullif` handling -  move concatenation with `MST` outside of the `coalesce` call (and remove it from `nullif`'s) - `coalesce(nullif(field, ''), nullif(...),..) || 'MST'`

Comment: I tried that before posting the question and it still produces the same error when I run it unfortunately

Comment: @adamctifacts as I mentioned in the comments to the question - your `nullif`'s are not doing what you are expecting, move concatenation with `MST` outside of coalesce - `coalesce(nullif(field, ''), nullif(...),..) || 'MST'`

Comment: so that was indeed the problem so thank you. If you want to post an answer to the question, I will upvote it and mark it answered!!!